# javascript compare two DOM trees

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to compare the change of a DOM node after a user event is fired on it; but I don't know on which element a user would fire, so my idea is to (1) save the DOM tree before an event and (2) compare the saved tree with the updated DOM tree when an event is fired.

My question are
(1) is there any better way?  and
(2) if there is no other way, what would be the fast algorithm to compare two DOM trees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since events bubble up, you could simply attach an event listener to the `window` object which catches all events, regardless of where they originated. You can examine the passed `event` object for [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target) to see where it originated.

Comment: guys, what would you recommend to check the change of a DOM tree, such as a node deleted or added.

Comment: @Paul You aren't in control of the functions that will be executed on the DOM elements? Otherwise you should know. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how complex a change you're expecting, but one possible "better" way would be to make use of [the built in DOM events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents). Specifically, the `DOMSubtreeModified` event will fire whenever the part of the DOM tree you're watching gets changed.

Comment: The attach a `DOMSubtreeModified` listener to the document.

Comment: The built-in DOM events don't work in IE, so this may not be a viable solution anyway.

Comment: Should more than one answer be selected as accepted answer, I would have added this answer as an accepted answer too...